# Remove white space in ggarrange, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, ggpubr

Say I have three SQUARE plots p1 p2 p3 made from the `ggplot2` package. I applied `ggarrange` command under `ggpubr` package to make a 1*3 plot after that. Here are the commands:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(gridExtra)
data <- data.frame(matrix(seq(1, 30, 1), 2))

for(i in 1:5){
  plot1 <- ggplot(data = data, aes(y = data[, (i*3-2)])) + 
      theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
  plot2 <- ggplot(data = data, aes(y = data[, (i*3-1)])) + 
      theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
  plot3 <- ggplot(data = data, aes(y = data[, (i*3)])) + 
      theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
  p <- ggarrange(plot1, plot2, plot3,
                 ncol = 3, common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")
  grid.arrange(p, top = paste(colnames(data)[i]), heights = c(1, 1))
}
```

The rmarkdown output (below) shows a large white space below the arranged plots:

[image]

Is there any way to remove it? What I thought is to change the default size of canvas..

Comment: It's very hard to say without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example): we can't see your data, your individual plots, or your final plot that you're trying to debug.

Comment: I have updated my question, hopefully it is more clear. The data itself is not important here.

Comment: The code from your example doesn't generate plots with a fixed amount of white space in R / Rstudio. You may want to check (& change) your default figure size in your rmarkdown document instead?

Comment: Thanks Z.Lin, to change the default figure size in rmarkdown it squeezes each plot. I finally gave up using the command "ggarrange" and used grid.arrange to make the change.

Comment: I'd love to see your code for this, I'm currently using ggarrange and can't get rid of the white space between each plot